Importing Python modules from a subdirectory
How can i import my module lib.py in my script module1.py from the following directory structure?
|-
|-lib/lib.py
|-module1/module1.py


This is very, very depend on the use case.

For personal usage, I will add the path of the main folder to PYTHONPATH, then import it with: import lib.lib.
If lib is an actual package, you can (and should) probably install it and import it the same way.
The last case I can think of for now is that if lib and module1 are under the same package already, you can use relative import as well: from ..lib import lib, or something similar.


I comment here because you need 50 rep to comment on other users posts: affecting the PYTHONPATH via sys.path is consider bad practice. For instance, see - https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/79tzt3/comment/dp4u8mv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

For your question I followed following steps and it worked for me: 
Step 1: create a file init.py in lib folder 
Step 2: Add path using sys
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'\path of your lib folder')
from lib import function_name 
print(function_name())

